# Correctly implementing specific formula into python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math, linear-algebra

This may be more of a math question, rather than a programing question but I am absolutely stuck and the problem occured to me while implementing it in python via `numpy`.
So, in my Machine Learning course the professor constructed an estimator for `Linear Regression` which resulted into the following equation for finding the `weight vector` with the labels `y` and data `x`:

[image]

As I understood it for the first part of the equation, I should just multiply the `vector x` with the `vector x transposed`. This results into a `matrix` which I should take the `inverse` from. Unfortunately taking the `inverse` isn't possible because the resulting matrix has a `determinant with the value of 0`. The way I understand it is that no matter how I change the x-vector, the equation will always result in a determinant with a value of zero.

Could it be that I am interpreting the equation in a wrong way? Or that I shouldn't do the calculation on a whole vector but rather run through the equation with every single datapoint iteratively (Imo it wouldn't make sense to transpose a single x value). So I'm not sure about that.

In Python code I had the equation as follows: `a = (np.linalg.inv(x * x.reshape(-1,1)))*(x*y)`

With x and y being simple `numpy arrays`, it throws the following Error: `LinAlgError: Singular matrix`.

Comment: I was referring to the '-1' as inverse. The 'i' is part of the summation

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Looks like this term is a scalar value. I assume `n` is number of examples.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer and yes, n is the number of examples. 
If the term results into a scalar value, wouldn't it be impossible to take the inverse of it? 
I guess I am falsely interpreting your comment so I am asking you kindly to explain it to me :)

Comment: I think it's scalar value with exponent `-1` which is `1/scalar_value`.

Comment: Now I understood it! Thank you a lot for helping me out.

Comment: Of course. One last question: Shall I calculate the scalar for every single value or the whole vector? If I do it with the whole vector I end up with only one value for w, leaving only room for a slope but no offset, etc. Sorry if I am struggling to understand. I am very new to the field (as you can see)

Answer (score 0):

In Numpy this is effectively

```
w = x.dot(y) / x.dot(x)
```

Both inner products are best represented as dot-products.